# Relational database and PHP: one-to-many relations with multiple one-tables

Tags: mysql, database

Let’s assume there are some rows in a table `cars`, and each of these rows has an owner. If this owner were always a person (conveniently situated in a table `persons`), this would be your standard one-to-many relation.

However, what if the owner could not only be a person, but also a company (in a table `companies`)? How would this relationship be modeled and how would it be handled in PHP?

My first idea was to create a column `person` and a column `company` and check that one of them always stays `NULL`, while the other is filled – however, that seems somewhat inelegant and becomes impractical once there is a higher number of possible related tables.

My current assumption would be to not simply create the foreign key as an integer column `person` in the table, but to create a further table called `tables`, which gives IDs to the tables, and then split the foreign key into two integer columns: `owner_table`, containing the ID of the table (e.g. 0 for `persons` and 1 for `companies`), and `owner_id`, containing the owner ID.

Is this a viable and practical solution or is there some standard design pattern regarding such issues? Is there a name for this type of problem? And are there any PHP frameworks supporting such relations?

EDIT: Found a solution: Such structures are called polymorphic relations, and [Laravel supports them](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#polymorphic-relations).

Comment: This question has nothing to do with php, this is a pure sql question. I suggest you remove the tag `php`.

Comment: @arkascha, I’d rather not – my main goal is to find a PHP framework supporting such data structures. I’ve searched through multiple frameworks by now and either this functionality is implemented nowhere or it is hidden under some keyword unbeknownst to me.

Comment: No, it does not make sense to implement such a specific model in a framework. Frameworks are more general. That is why I say that this has nothing to do with php. The closest you could come to get some form of "black box" would be to use `views` inside the database server to model that mapping of tables to objects or lists. But again that has nothing to do with php.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn’t aware this was such a specific issue – I rather took it for a core issue of ORM, as this use case pops up over and over in OO data management. Seeing that it is easy to create such data models in PHP, I guessed there would have been a standard way to save them in a database. I’ve removed the PHP tag and will just hope that some framework suggestions come up anyway.

Comment: I kindly suggest to better understand how relational models work.  An owner is always an owner, and it can be a person or a company.  But also think that like in real world, any asset like a car, can have two or more owners.

Comment: @datelligent, I’m aware of that – the question was rather whether there is a standard pattern to model such a relation, and if this pattern is implemented in any PHP frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it.

You can go with two nullable foreign keys: one referencing company and the other user. Then you can have a [check constraint](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ddl-constraints.html) which assure you one is null. With PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE car{
    <your car fields>
    company_id INT REFERENCES car,
    person_id INT REFERENCES person,
    CHECK(company_id IS NULL AND person_id IS NOT NULL 
       OR company_id IS NOT NULL AND person_id IS NULL)
};
```

Or you can use [table inheritance](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ddl-constraints.html) (beware their limitations)

```
CREATE TABLE car_owner{
    car_owner_id SERIAL
};

CREATE TABLE company{
   <company fields>
} INHERITS(car_owner);

CREATE TABLE person{
   <person fields>
} INHERITS(car_owner);

CREATE TABLE car{
   <car fields>
   car_owner_id INT REFERENCES car_owner
};
```